# copy table from libreoffice calc in word document

Tags: libreoffice

When I use libreoffice calc, I copy my table from libreoffice calc in libreoffice writer. But when I want to save de document in word type, the table was disappear.. So what must I do? cause almost all my friend didn't use libreoffice writer.. Thank you so much

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem, even if I uncheck all MS compatibility options in `extra (from the menu) > options > load/save`, all tables & sheets etc are saved. you could try those settings nevertheless. Does the problem only occur on their computer or are the tables lost at your's too?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on LibreOffice, but I believe the reason copying and pasting doesn't result in a visible table is that the table shown in Calc is merely an instrument (like ruler lines) rather than part of the document itself.

That said if you save the Calc file as .html then open the .html file in Writer and save as a document you can get a visible table, because it forces table to be written to the document as data.

## Steps:

1. Open your Calc file and save as a .html file.
2. Open Writer and then open the .html file.
3. Save the file as a document (.odt, .doc, .docx, and etc).

## Additional Resources:

Video of the process (MP4 1.70MB) = https://copy.com/s3JeFSJrR4pa